# Should One say Shehechyanu on world events?

Tags: blessing, current-events

The bracha of Shehechyanu (according to [here](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehecheyanu#Shehecheyanu_for_new_clothes_or_other_items)) was instituted to be said "for uncommon or periodical occurrences and experiences, such as holidays and their mitzvot, fruits in their new season, major purchases, **and exciting news**." (emphasis mine)

I can't find any solid information about what constitutes "exciting news" and whether that is personal news or news of world import (the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shehecheyanu) page mentions the founding of the State of Israel). Would an end to a war, or the announcement of a treaty, or a successful vaccine to a world wide plague allow for a bracha to be made?

Comment: Vaccines rarely have binary "success" moments like a war treaty. There could easily be a somewhat helpful vaccine which over a long period of time slowly curbs a pandemic in particular areas or something like that

Comment: I'd think it would be hatov vehameitiv, not shehecheyanu

Comment: @Heshy I'm reading the S"A 222.1 and I can see that way of thinking.

Answer (score -2):

Shehechiyanu is for experiences -- "God, you kept me alive to this momentous occasion that I'm feeling right now"; *hatov vehameitiv* upon hearing good news -- "God, you do good things like the one I just heard about."

Thus, for example, *hatov vehameitiv* upon **hearing** "you had a boy!", vs. *shehechiyanu* upon **seeing** your newborn daughter.

Thus, hearing news of vaccine would be *hatov vehameitiv*; not sure what the experiential equivalent would be (it's the removal of a negative) ... people tend not to think of getting shots as momentous occasions ...